# Removing duplicated options from select box in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I want to generate select boxes based on the number of elements in the `$chosen` array and each of them will have the default selected options. The first one is `A`, and the second one is `D`. The following code is almost okay except I want to remove the duplicated options. Here's the output:

```
<select>
   <option>Select</option>
   <option value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="D">D</option>
   <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<select>
 <option>Select</option>
 <option value="D" selected="selected">D</option>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

I tried `array_merge` with `array_unique` to merge `$options` and `$chosen` before `foreach($options as $option)` but it isn't working. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
<?php

$options = array("A","B","C","D","E");
$chosens = array("A","D");


foreach($chosens as $chosen)
{
  print "<select><option>Select</option>";

  if(in_array($chosen,$options))
  {
    print "<option value='".$chosen."' selected='selected'>$chosen</option>";
  }

 /* $options = array_unique(array_merge($chosen,$options)); */

    foreach($options as $option)
    {
      print "<option value='".$option."'>$option</option>";

    }

  print "</select>";
}

?>*
```

Comment: I think You need a check if the value in `chosens` array already exists in `options` array

Comment: You want values in $chosen array to be selected ?

Comment: @TBI, yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Just check if `$option == $chosen` in the second foreach loop, you can remove the `in_array()` condition, [here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nCRBIR)

Comment: yes, but there are two values in $chosen...it will override.

Comment: @TBI no there isn't, `$chosen` is a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, just a simple if condition is enough. Like this:

```
<?php

$options = array("A","B","C","D","E");
$chosens = array("A","D");

?>

<?php foreach($chosens as $chosen): ?>
    <select name="">
    <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>" <?php echo ($option == $chosen) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```